# Sending UK visa application to New York

Tags: paperwork, standard-visitor-visas, applications, south-african-citizens, falkland-islands

I filled in the online application for UK (Gibraltar, Overseas teritory) visa. I am a South African living in Falkland Islands. I did the biometrics locally in Falkland Islands and now have all documents ready to send to New York. The online application did however not allow me to make payment. Where do I pay for my visa application and can I send my application to New York without having made any payment yet?

Comment: Slightly puzzled - AFAIK the online application for the Falklands https://www.visa4uk.fco.gov.uk/Home/ViewFAQ normally requires payment before you can book your biometric appointment. Did you apply through an agent?

Comment: No, I did online application myself, and it did not allow me to pay or make appointment, after submitting, those 2 options (blocks) where faded out. After enquiring locally and Gibraltar customs, we manage to continue with biometric, but no one know where I should pay at the moment.

Comment: I haven’t seen this particular question come up on TSE before. I suspect the solution might have to be for you to call or email UKVI https://www.gov.uk/contact-ukvi-inside-outside-uk, for which there is a fee